# how to get id from Url in python django last v?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to get the id from url in Django for a python programming language but I face the problem page no found. I want the code for this in the last version in Django because I have it please help me

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend you to follow the tutorial in the official Django web page.
You will learn Django urls, models and views basics there. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

The answer to your question you can find on the 3rd page of the tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views